# Align text vertically center next to image

Tags: html, css

Currently my text appears at the top of the page. I'd like it aligned centrally vertically - so it seems like it's in the middle of the logo, but aligned to the right.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qz65n29f/

```css
.title {
    float:left
}

.text-right {
    float:right
}

li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left
}
```

```html
<header>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-12 columns">
                    <div class="small-2 columns">
                        <div class="title">
                            <a href="" title=""><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QOiAoWEw0Vc/UcRdzycinmI/AAAAAAAAABQ/cb2kQ7cJlsY/s200/Google_chrome_logo.png" alt="" class="logo" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-10 columns">
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <nav class="primary right">
                                <div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu menu inline naked horizontal bold"><li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-88 current_page_item menu-item-102"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/home/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/service-map/">Resources</a></li>
</ul></div>                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
</header>
```

Comment: The problem is cruft. Please simplify your code or show all CSS. You currently have div upon div with classes upon classes, so we have no idea how your final design actually looks, so we cant suggest something like `position: relative; top: calc(50%); transform: translateY(-50%);` since I dont know if your wrapping div will have any height to offset from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS if you dont mind ill alter the CSS a little.

```
.small-2.columns{
    display: table-cell;
}

.medium-12.columns{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}


li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qz65n29f/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Please use padding according to the height of your logo

```css
.title {
    float:left
}

.text-right {
    float:right;
    padding:65px 0px;
}

li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left
}
```

```html
<header>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-12 columns">
                    <div class="small-2 columns">
                        <div class="title">
                            <a href="" title=""><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QOiAoWEw0Vc/UcRdzycinmI/AAAAAAAAABQ/cb2kQ7cJlsY/s200/Google_chrome_logo.png" alt="" class="logo" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-10 columns">
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <nav class="primary right">
                                <div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu menu inline naked horizontal bold"><li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-88 current_page_item menu-item-102"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/home/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/service-map/">Resources</a></li>
</ul></div>                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This isn't very scalable, it works, but it means changing your CSS every time your logo changes size a bit. I know that doesn't happen often but it's possible to do it so it centers automatically, but we need more info for that.